# Cannot open BitLocker encrypted drive or use recovery key

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have encrypted my D: drive with BitLocker but the drive fails to open even when I enter the correct password. The recovery key is also not working.

An error message pops up stating:

> BitLocker Drive Encryption failed to recover from an abruptly terminated conversion. This could be due to either all conversion logs being corrupted or the media being write-protected.

How can I fix this? All my important files are on this drive.

Comment: There is a [BitLocker Repair Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17294) but you should include some information about how BitLocker stopped working; power outtage, windows crash, normal operation etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this prompt your disc is corrupt and cannot be recovered.
You must format the drive to be able to use it again.
Everything on the drive will be lost.